# What would a word or words be for horrendous, stressful, controlled "chaos" be? Such as a team working on a trauma in an emergency room setting?

Tags: synonyms

Word for Opposite of uncontrolled chaos such as controlled but stressful emergency setting with a team of emergency workers all multitasking in a combined effort.

Answer (score 1):

**Pressure Cooker** captures the stressful, chaotic environment rather well.

> **Pressure Cooker** - An environment where people are faced with urgent responsibilities, with demanding and hectic workloads and tight deadlines.

Answer (score 0):

You could call it a *hive of activity*.

> **Hive of activity**
>   a ​place where a lot of ​people are ​working very hard: *The ​whole ​house was a hive of ​activity on the ​day before the ​wedding*.
>   [- Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-hive-of-activity-industry)